# Access an object of one class in other codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, class, object

I have two controller classes in my codeigniter application, say class A and B.I just want to create an object of class A and access the functions declared in class A from class B.Something like:-

```
class A extends someclass
{
public function function1(){

$this->load->view('welcome_message');  
}       
}
}

class B extends someclass2
{
protected $object;
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();

$this->objectA = new A();
}       
}
}
```

I want to access the function function1 from class B using the object objectA. How can i do this?
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, can i try some other method than libraries?when i try this i got an error like, Cannot modify header information - .Actually am working on codeigniter unit testing.Please suggest some methods rather than libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-controller access goes against CI best practice.

Either inherit both controllers from a controller that holds this common functionality (don't forget to prefix the function with '_' so it's inaccessible via url routing) or create a library that contains your re-usable functionality. A helper can also work.

Answer (score 1):

well actually this is not the proper way in codeigniter. Actually when you have common functions in and you want to use them in 2 or more controllers. The best way is to create base controller in core folder with name of MY_Contoller and extend it from CI_Contoller. Write your common function in MY_Contoller. Now you have to extend all your controllers from MY_Contoller instead of CI_Contoller. You can do the same with Model.

Comment: Suppose i have made two controllers in application/controllers folder myself.Consider these two classes A and B in these two controllers.Can i create object of one class (say A) and access the functions of other class (class B)? what i tried to do is, i have imported one controller class to the other using require(application /controller/controller1) in controller2, but am getting some errors.?Is it possible that way?

Comment: what is your situation, I mean why do you need it>

Comment: I haven't tried it because never got in situation. but if you want to create its object in your class B, you first include class A in you Class B. 
include("A.php"); use this line at the beginning. But I am not sure it will work